# Rank one matrix

Tags: matrices

Given that I know that the matrix $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times m}$ satisfies that:
$$\mathbf{W}^\top\mathbf{W} = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{a}^\top$$
Where $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$ is a column vector.

Does this mean $\mathbf{W}$ is a rank one matrix, meaning it's columns are all identical up to some multiplicative scale?

Comment: Since for all vectors $x$ $(W^\prime W)x=(aa^\prime)x=a(a^\prime x)$ is a scalar multiple of $a,$ the rank of $WW^\prime$ cannot exceed $1$ by definition. You can also use the definition of matrix multiplication to (immediately) conclude the columns are all multiples of $a$ and the scale factor for column $j$ of $W^\prime W$ is $a_j.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=0$, then rank of $W$ is $0$.

Otherwise, you are right, the rank of $W$ is $1$. $$rank(W^TW)=1,$$

Let $W=U\Sigma V^T$, then $W^TW=V\Sigma^T\Sigma V^T$, and we can see that the rank of $W^TW$ and the rank of $W$ is the same.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\Sigma$ and $V$ in your answer?

Comment: I wrote it as the [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $W$.